# Importar código do github para o eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, git, eclipse, github

Tenho um código que gostaria de importar para o meu eclipse através do download do zip,entretanto na hora de importar da o seguinte erro

> No projects are found to import

Pesquisando sobre as funcionalidades do git ,descobri que tem o comando clone que configurando com o github é possível baixar por linha de comando o projeto mas mesmo assim é necessário a importação do projeto no eclipse.

Como importar um projeto Java do github pro meu eclipse podendo executar o mesmo ?

Projeto que desejo baixar. 
https://gist.github.com/basavesh/4044475

Comment: O projeto é maven?

Comment: Projeto Java sem persistência  no caso desktop..

Comment: Posta o link do github pra a gente ver como está o código

Comment: Link github do projeto adicionado na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não é um repositório git nem um projeto Java.

É apenas uma classe Java isolada em um Gist.

O [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/) é uma forma simples de compartilhar código, notas, textos e etc. É algo como o [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).
Não é um repositório git.
[Esse](https://github.com/victorjordan95/krusty-api) é um exemplo de um repositório git com um projeto Java usando Maven.

---

Para que você consiga "ter" essa classe, não tem segredo: crie um projeto Java no Eclipse, crie uma classe chamada `DoublyLinkedList` e copie o conteúdo do Gist e cole na sua classe.
É assim que se utiliza um código que está no Gist.